# how to add intent to manifest?

Tags: android, android-intent, manifest

i have this intent in my app to move to another activity to add details for the contact using submenu

```
Intent k = new Intent();// = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AddContact.class);
            k.setAction("com.example.dbtest2.AddContact");
            k.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
            startActivity(k);
```

and this is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dbtest2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AddContacts">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.example.dbtest2.k"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

but the logcat says no activity found to handle intent! 
the activity added to manifest which is .addContact .. did i add the intent and the activity to the manifest correctly?

Comment: `<activity android:name=".AddContacts">` you declared AddContact**s**. Not AddContact.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only starting this `Activity` from your own application, you shouldn't do it like this. You should remove the `intent-filter` from the manifest and just launch the `Activity` using an explicit `Intent`, like this:

```
Intent k = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddContacts.class);
startActivity(k);
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:name=".AddContacts"` should be changed to `android:name=".AddContact".`
That is why your activity is not found.